# R/Python method to combine multiple SPSS-style crosstables into one table

Tags: python, r, crosstab

My supervisor wants a single table comparing multiple different categorical variables against another categorical variable. For example, the attached image
[x-tab cross table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V6Xp.png)
is found here https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/no-need-for-spss-beautiful-output-in-r-rstats/ is made from R sjt.xtab() [though the function name has since changed].

I could use sjt.xtab() to create another cross-table with different index variables, for example age category (0-15, 16-29, and etc) with the same column variables (dependency level). What I need to be able to do is combine both of these crosstables into one table where the column categories stay in the same position and several different categorical variables (sex, age categories, shoe size, and etc) are listed in the index. This doesn't seem statistically correct as it would appear to duplicate numbers, but my supervisor just wants it for referencing reasons not publication.

Is there any way to do this in R or python? Happy to clarify my question if needed!

Edit, Here is a terribly edited Microsoft Paint example of what I am looking for [Combined cross-tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0chNo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may do that with GT tables: https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html